# Source for historical Argentina aerial WMS

Tags: geospatial

I'm looking for information on an area between Alta Gracia - Córdoba from c. pre-1993 (anything in the 1970s or 1980s will help). Is anyone able to direct me towards any sources of historical aerial imagery in Argentina, or any WMS sources?